# Laravel Sidebar active menu, error get URI paramters

Tags: laravel, parameters, uri, sidebar

My Route :

```
Route::get('/form2/{karyawan}/maintenance', 'KaryawanController@editMaintenance')->name('user.edit_maintenance');
```

Sidebar :

```
<li><a href="{{ route('user.edit_maintenance') }}" class="{{ Request::is('/form2/*/maintenance') ? 'active' : '' }}"><i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i> <span>Form</span></a></li>
```

Error : Missing required parameters for [Route: user.edit_maintenance] [URI: form2/{karyawan}/maintenance].

How to solve this sidebar ?

Comment: this is route error. you need to pass {karyawan} in URL. `{{ route('user.edit_maintenance',$karyawan) }}`

Comment: Request::is('/form2*maintenance')) ? 'active' : ''  try this

Comment: its work, but if i move to another url it will show "Undefined variable: karyawan"

Comment: You need to send parameter to this link. That's why you get a missing parameter error. Sample `href="{{ route('user.edit_maintenance', $karyawan }}"`

Comment: <li><a href="{{ route('user.edit_maintenance', $karyawan}}" class="{{ Request::is('/form2*maintenance') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i> <span>Form</span></a>
        </li> try this

Comment: <li><a href="{{ route('user.edit_maintenance', $karyawan') }}" class="{{ Request::is('/form2*maintenance') ? 'active' : '' }}"><i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i> <span>Form 002</span></a></li>

its work for route KaryawanController.
but for other controller it is get error 
error : $karyawan is undefined. 
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $karyawan }} with {{ $karyawan ?? '' }}

Comment: Probably you new on Laravel. I wrote at the top but I guess you don't know exactly how the Routing thing works so read Laravel Routing in docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing @ITNewbie